# PERL - Net::Websocket::Server with external periodic event

Tags: perl, events, websocket

In my server program I need to have ability to iterate every 5 minutes through all opened connections and see which is really "active" or not.

I know that the best approach is to use "heart beat", but then, the server need to have somehow ability to check weather the connection is "off" in order to delete the associated "user parameters" that is attached to the connection.

My first approach was to use "Async" module, but this works in a separate process - so I cannot delete any element from the main process unless I use a technique to invoke a subroutine from the main process called from the child process (I don't know how, any help will be warmly welcomed).

Another possibility using Async is create a static client that is all the time on (also in the server) and sending "commands" to the server, but to me it looks "too exaggerating" to create such "wasting memory" client in the server, and also "eat" CPU time (I think much more than simple event like equivalent to "setTimeout" in JS).

Yet another approach is to use EV: But when I call EV::run it will NOT RUN anything ELSE than this "periodic event" - means that it will not reach the next line where the ->Start for the server is.
Placing it after the ->Start will make this event useless too: As the server works the program will not go behind the ->Start line.
Using EV::run EV::RUN_NOWAIT; will make the server work, but the EV will somehow not work, for a strange reason (Anyone know how can I still make it work?)

I prefer to not use Net::Websocket::EV, because as per their script, it doesn't do the handshake automatically, and many things (as well as SSL connection that I have) I will need to do manually and for me it is change a lot in my program.

PROBLEM SUMMARY:
How to make the code in EV run every 5 minutes, together with the server?

```
my %CON; # Connections (And user data) hash

my $__ConChk=EV::periodic 0, 300, 0, sub {
my @l=keys %CON;
for(my $i=0 ; $i<@l ; $i++) {
    if($CON{$l[$i]}{"T"}+3600<time()) { # I give one hour time to be completely offline (for different reasons)
        $CON{$l[$i]}{"C"}->disconnect(); delete $CON{$l[$i]};
    }
}
};
EV::run EV::RUN_NOWAIT; # This is not working - Seems to be ignored!

Net::WebSocket::Server->new(
listen => $ssl, # Earlier preset
silence_max=>60, # Time to just shut the connection off, but don't delete user data
on_connect => sub {
    my($serv,$conn)=@_;
    my $cid; # Connection ID (for the hash)

    $conn->on(
        handshake => sub {
            my($conn,$handshake)=@_;
            # Create user data in $CON{$cid}
        },
        binary => sub {
            $CON{$cid}{"T"}=time();
            # Handling of single incomming message (command)
        },
        disconnect => sub {
            # Do NOT DELETE THE ENTRY!! Maybe the connection drop due to instability!!
        }
    );
}
)->start; # This will run - but ignoring EV::run - what to do....?
undef $__ConChk;
```

Comment: A short look at the Net::WebSocket::Server documentation shows an `on_tick` handler which together with `tick_period` attribute seems to  exactly offer what you want, i.e. periodic actions. Why don't you use this one? See the second example [in the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::WebSocket::Server#SYNOPSIS) for the details.

Comment: I have tried it too, I wonder why it is not working.....

Comment: Maybe you should then ask a question with code which shows that it does not work how it is supposed to according to the documentation instead of trying to find other and more complex ways which don't work for you either. Also, make sure that the code is complete enough so that your problem can be reproduced by others. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And, please properly indent the code you have in your question.

Comment: I retried now, and I found what was my problem, now it is working with the on_tick, thanks a lot:)